# rstudio/shinyapps - Error in set(new) : cannot change working directory

Tags: r, shiny

I removed shinyapps and tried to install it again, but what I get is an error.

```
remove.packages("shinyapps", "C:/Users/xxx/Documents/R/win-library/3.1")
```

to install it back,

```
> devtools::install_github('rstudio/shinyapps')
Downloading github repo rstudio/shinyapps@master
Installing shinyapps
Error in set(new) : cannot change working directory
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I have gotten around this problem by running R/Rstudio as admin, worth a shot

Comment: how do I run R/Rstudio as admin?

Comment: On windows, right click on the icon and select "Run as administrator"

Comment: Thanks!. It works finally! What a pain in using Shiny! It sucks!

Comment: Its not Shiny persay... This error sometimes occurs for plain old installation of packages, I am assuming that it has to do with the file permissions of your default lib directory but am going to wait around for one of the R elite to come give a complete answer.